# microsoft visual studio error when running a project C file with custom header

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

fatal error C1853: 'Debug\t1.pch' precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)

What does that mean and how do i fix it?

This is my first time using microsoft visual studio and using a project file with it.

thank you

Comment: Remove your `Debug\t1.pch` or remove the `debug` folder alltogether.

Comment: where can i find that?

Comment: the `debug` directory is somehere near to your .cpp files.

Comment: are you trying to load a project created with a previous version of visual studio or are you making a new project?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126717/en